# Powershell - Get yesterday's file name in real time

Tags: powershell

I'm noob in PowerShell and trying to use it to send email with attachment.

Today's date is 2021-02-18. I have a folder which have many files created by ERP system everyday, the files name are as follows:

```
2021-2-17WO_rate.xlsx
2021-2-16WO_rate.xlsx
2021-2-15WO_rate.xlsx
2021-2-14WO_rate.xlsx
2021-2-13WO_rate.xlsx
2021-2-12WO_rate.xlsx
...
```

I would like the script always choose the newest file as the attachment

`(Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')` can get the yesterday date, but when I intergrate it in to below script, it fails. I have no idea how to solve it after search the many websites.

Anyone can help me? much appreciate.

The code I use is as follows:

```
$UserName = "XXXX@XXXXX.com"      
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString XXXXXX -AsPlainText –Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($UserName,$Password)
$a = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')


$mailParams = @{
    SmtpServer                 = 'smtp.office365.com'
    Port                       = '587' # or '25' if not using TLS
    UseSSL                     = $true ## or not if using non-TLS
    BodyasHtml                 = $true
    Credential                 = $cred
    From                       = $UserName
    To                         = 'XXXXXX'
    Subject                    = "WORK ORDER STATUS"
    Body                       = 'XXXXXXX'
    Attachments                = '\\us-fs\us-Groups\Operationsus\Public\erpoutput\date\${a}WO_rate.xlsx'
    DeliveryNotificationOption = 'OnFailure', 'OnSuccess'
}
Send-MailMessage @mailParams
```

Comment: instead of converting yesterday to a date STRING, leave it as a datetime OBJECT. then do your check by converting the file names to datetime objects. it looks like you can split the `.BaseName` on `WO_` and take the 1st part to get the date string, then convert it to a date object with `Get-Date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the name is not populated is because you used single quotation mark `'`. If you want to have the value from the variable, you need to use double quotation string `"`:

```
<# Only relevant parts of the script, other lines removed #>

# Specify correct formatting string, based on the information from the question it should be either
$dataFormat = 'yyyy-M-d'
# or
$dataFormat = 'yyyy-M-dd'

$formattedDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString($dataFormat)


$mailParams = @{
    <# other params #>
    Attachments                = "\\us-fs\us-Groups\Operationsus\Public\erpoutput\date\${formattedDate}WO_rate.xlsx"
}
Send-MailMessage @mailParams
```

**NOTE**: I also changed variable name so that it's obvious what it is used for.

---

<sup>Edit: corrected date format based on [@Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo)'s comment</sup>

Comment: Also should use a `$` in front of the variable, either $a or $formattedDate

Comment: If you mean `${$formattedDate}WO_rate` then yes, that's how I'd use it, but `${formattedDate}WO_rate` is working fine as I checked. For sure `$formattedDateWO_rate.xlsx` won't work in that case as it's followed by alphanumeric characters.

Comment: `ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')` should be `ToString('yyyy-M-dd')` or even `ToString('yyyy-M-d')` if the examples are correct (`2021-2-17WO_rate.xlsx` does not have a leading zero for M). As for the `dd` we can't be sure because the examples show no date where the day is less than 10..

Comment: thanks all fo you!!! I also find another way that works  $formattedDate`WO_rate.xlsx, powershell is crazy~~

Answer (score 0):

If the file is not modified since *yesterday* as well you can retrieve the path of the last file modified *yesterday* in the folder and use that as the attachment

```
$file = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\path\to\folder' -Filter '*.xlxs' -File |     # get all files with xlxs extension in path
    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime.Date -eq (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).Date } | # files that were last written to yesterday
    Sort-Object LastWriteTime |                                              # sort by lastwrite time in ascending order 
    Select-Object -Last 1 |                                                  # select only the last file on the list
    ForEach-Object FullName                                                  # output the full file path

$UserName = "XXXX@XXXXX.com"      
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString XXXXXX -AsPlainText –Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($UserName,$Password)
$a = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')


$mailParams = @{
    SmtpServer                 = 'smtp.office365.com'
    Port                       = '587' # or '25' if not using TLS
    UseSSL                     = $true ## or not if using non-TLS
    BodyasHtml                 = $true
    Credential                 = $cred
    From                       = $UserName
    To                         = 'XXXXXX'
    Subject                    = "WORK ORDER STATUS"
    Body                       = 'XXXXXXX'
    Attachments                = $file   # <--------------
    DeliveryNotificationOption = 'OnFailure', 'OnSuccess'
}
Send-MailMessage @mailParams
```